# Query Deferred for stacking calls

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Having the following 3 functions:

```
var f1 = function(e) { setTimeout(function () { return e + 1;}, 1000); }
var f2 = function(e) { setTimeout(function () { return e + 5;}, 1000); }
var f3 = function(e) { setTimeout(function () { return e + 7;}, 1000); }
```

how do I chain the calls using jQuery.Deferred such that my call will look like:

```
$.when(f1()).then(f2()).then(f3()).done(function(result){ /* I want it to be 13 when called with 0! */ });
```

and then call the stack with 0 as input parameter?

I currently use nested `ready: function(){}` but looking to move on to something more manageable.

Just to summarize I'm looking for a way to stack up arbitrary service calls so that they'll run in a predetermined order and the output of each N function will be used as input for N+1 one.

I want to keep my functions flat and as clean from jQuery code as possible. It'd be nice to find a way to pass the root value in a nice way rather than hardcoding it in a function call itself.

I can see a sample of using `then` in conjunction with multiple arguments passed into `$.when(f1, f2, f3).then(result1, result2, result3)` - but that's not what I'm after.

Here's what I have so far:

http://jsbin.com/yaqitagelazo/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/external/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        $(function() {

            var first = function (e) {
                var d = $.Deferred();

                setTimeout(function () {

                    e = e + 1;
                    d.resolve(e);
                }, 1000);

                return d.promise();
            };

            var second = function (e) {
                var d = $.Deferred();

                e = e + 5;

                setTimeout(function () {

                    d.resolve(e);

                }, 1000);

                return d.promise();
            };

            // so far so good, passing 0 right in the call doesn't look good.
            // Q: how do I pass the value for the root function call?
            $.when(first(0)).done(function(result) { alert(result); }); 

            // Q: doesn't work at all returns on first return.
            $.when(first(0))
                .then(second())
                .done(function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                });
        });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you should start reading about promises, try to implement your above sequence with promises and then come back here if/when you get stuck somewhere. Per the StackOverflow guidelines, a question should show a reasonable effort at researching and solving the problem yourself.  You can start reading [here](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) and [here](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/2/8/fun-with-jquery-deferred) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983331/using-jquery-deferred-to-avoid-nested-settimeout-callbacks).

Comment: Code sample attached.

Comment: Tried defining `e` as a variable outside of individual functions ?

Comment: guest271314 could you craft a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var _e = {
  e : 0
};

var f1 = function(e) { 
    return new $.Deferred(function(j) {
        _e.e = e + 1; 
        $.when(f2(5), f3(7))
        .done(function(n) {
            setTimeout(function() { 
                j.resolve(n)
            }, 1000)
        }); 
        return j.promise()
    }) 
};

var f2 = f3 = function(n) {
    _e.e = _e.e + n; 
    var dfd = new $.Deferred(); 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        dfd.resolve(_e.e)
    },1000); 
    return dfd.promise() 
};

f1(0).done(function(res) {
  console.log(res)
});
```

---

Alternatively ,

independent functions

```
var _e = {
    e : 0 
};

var f1 = function() { 
  return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) { 
    setTimeout(function () { 
      _e.e = _e.e + 1; dfd.resolve(_e.e);
    }, 1000); 
    return dfd.promise()
  }); 
};

var f2 = function() { 
  return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) { 
    setTimeout(function () { 
      _e.e = _e.e + 5; dfd.resolve(_e.e);
    }, 1000); 
    return dfd.promise()
  }); 
};

var f3 = function() { 
  return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) { 
    setTimeout(function () { 
      _e.e = _e.e + 7; dfd.resolve(_e.e);
    }, 1000); 
    return dfd.promise()
  }); 
};

f1(), f2(), f3().done(function(res) {
  console.log(res)
})
```

---

Single function

```
var _e = {
    e : 0
};

var f1 = f2 = f3 = function(n) { 
  return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) { 
    setTimeout(function () { 
        _e.e = _e.e + n; dfd.resolve(_e.e);
    }, 3000); 
        return dfd.promise()
  }); 
};

f1(1), f2(5), f3(7).done(function(res) {
  console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: Thanks man. And this all is called great simplification over "ready" approach?:) LOL