# delay for jquery promises

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I cannot find `delay` or `wait` function for `jQuery` promises. I have found one function on the SO ([Using jQuery.Deferred to avoid nested setTimeout callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17983331/1048572)):

```
function delay(time) {
    return function () {
        console.log("Delaying");
        var ret = new $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            ret.resolve();
        }, time);
        return ret;
    };
}
```

And, it's the way how I use it:

```
 run: function () {
        return $()
            .promise()
            .then(function () {
                console.log("call together");
                console.log("call together");    
            })
            .then(delay(2000))
            .then(function () {
                console.log("call first");
            })
            .then(delay(2000))
            .then(function () {
                console.log("call second");
            })
    }
```

I want to extend promise or deferred object that I can write like:

```
run: function () {
            return $()
                .promise()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("call together");
                    console.log("call together");    
                })
                .delay(2000)
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("call first");
                })
                .delay(2000)
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("call second");
                })
        }
```

Comment: @guest271314: I need function exactly for promises. This function for effects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add methods to JQuery's promise object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30719454/1048572) (just add a `.delay` method instead of the `.catch`)

Comment: @jfriend00: Well of course [it is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30719727/1048572)… but not as easily as extending a prototype is.

Comment: @jfriend00: That code would work for all deferreds and promises that are constructed after the decorator code ran (including jqXHRs). But if you have further questions, let's discuss them over there :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Bergi says jQuery Deferreds/Promises are not extendible by prototypal inheritance.

Instead, the model adopted by jQuery is to allow individual Promise instances to be extended with the syntax :

```
deferred.promise(target);
//or, 
promise.promise(target); //(though the documentation doesn't make this clear)
// where `target` is an "object onto which the promise methods have to be attached"
// see https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/
```

By defining a constructor with a bunch of methods, any jQuery Deferred or Promise can be extended with the simple syntax

```
.promise(Constructor())
```

In my unpublished, undocumented jQuery promises Playground, the constructor is named `$P` and kept in the jQuery namespace, hence the actual syntax I use is :

```
.promise($.$P())
```

You need to be aware of that, for the most part, it's not necessary to call `$.$P()` explicitly as the Playground includes a `$.when_()` method that returns an already extended Promise.

Here's an abbreviated version of the Playground with just enough to provide a `.delay()` method :

```
(function($) {
    /* ***********************************
     * The $.$P function returns an object
     * designed to be extended with 
     * promise methods using the syntax :
     *    myDeferred.promise($.$P())
     *    myPromise.promise($.$P())
     * where `myDeferred`/`myPromise` 
     * are jQuery Deferred/Promise objects.
     * ***********************************/

    /* ***********************************
     * Methods
     * ***********************************/
    $.$P = function() {
        if (this instanceof $.$P) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return new $.$P();
        }
    };
    $.$P.prototype.then_ = function(fa, fb) {
        /* A promise method that is the same as .then()
         * but makes these extra methods available 
         * down-chain.
         */
        return this.then(fa||null, fb||null).promise($.$P());
    }
    $.$P.prototype.delay_ = function(ms) {
        /* A promise method that 
         * introduces a down-chain delay.
         */
        var promise = this;
        function f(method) {
            return function() { setTimeout(function(){ method.apply(null,this); }.bind(arguments), ms||0); };
        }
        return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) { 
            promise.then(f(dfrd.resolve), f(dfrd.reject));
        }).promise($.$P());
    }

    /* ***********************************
     * Utility functions
     * ***********************************/
    function consolidate(args) {
        /* Convert mixed promises/arrays_of_promises to single array.
         * Called by all the when_() methods below.
         */
        return Array.prototype.slice.apply(args).reduce(function(arr, current) {
            return arr.concat(current);
        }, []);
    }

    /* ***********************************
     * This section extends the jQuery namespace 
     * with a "jQuery.when_()" method.
     * ***********************************
     */
    $.extend({
        'when_': function() {
            return $.when.apply(null, consolidate(arguments)).promise($.$P()).then_(function() {
                return consolidate(arguments);
            });
        },
    });
})(jQuery);
```

*The full Playground also includes a whole bunch more static and promise-instance methods for other purposes, and developing them is the essence of the play.*

The ground-rules for using the Playgound are as follows :

- All the Playground's static and promise methods end in "_" underscore.
- Static methods, eg `$.when_()`, are made available just by installing the Playgound.
- Promises in a promise chain are extended by including a static method, eg `.when_()`, or chaining `.promise($.$P())`.
- In a promise chain, the extensions remain available (down the chain) by using "..._" methods rather than the standard methods, eg `.then_()` in place of `.then()`.

So here's how to use it to impose the delays required by the question :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var MYNAMESPACE = {
        run: function (t) {
            return $.when_()
            .then_(function () {
                log("call together");
                log("call together");    
            })
            .delay_(t)
            .then_(function () {
                log("call first");
            })
            .delay_(t)
            .then_(function () {
                log("call second");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r6hrtv1q/)**

In the demo, the button's click handler gives further indication of how the Playground can be used.

Provisos on using the Playground :

- As I say - it's a *playground*.
- As an adaptor for jQuery, not a patch, it is horribly inefficient in places. Worst aspect is that some methods create an intermediate promise in addition to the one they return.
- Not tested to the standards required for use in production code, so use with caution.

And lastly, only consider the above if you are determined to implement delay with jQuery. It's far far simpler to use a promise lib that already has a `.delay()` method.

Comment: You are master of promises. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

Try adding property `delay` to `jQuery.Deferred`

```
    delay: function(t) {
      return this.then(function() {
        var args = arguments;
        return new $.Deferred(function(d) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            // return `data`, if any, to next method, e.g., `.then`, in chain
            d.resolveWith(this, args)
          }.bind(this), t || 0)
        }).promise()
      })
    }
```

---

```js
(function($) {
  $.Deferred = function(a) {
    var b = [
        ["resolve", "done", $.Callbacks("once memory"), "resolved"],
        ["reject", "fail", $.Callbacks("once memory"), "rejected"],
        ["notify", "progress", $.Callbacks("memory")]
      ],
      c = "pending",
      d = {
        delay: function(t) {
          return this.then(function() {
            var args = arguments;
            return new $.Deferred(function(d) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                // return `data`, if any, to next method, e.g., `.then`, in chain
                d.resolveWith(this, args)
              }.bind(this), t || 0)
            }).promise()
          })
        },
        state: function() {
          return c
        },
        always: function() {
          return e.done(arguments).fail(arguments), this
        },
        then: function() {
          var a = arguments;
          return $.Deferred(function(c) {
            $.each(b, function(b, f) {
              var g = $.isFunction(a[b]) && a[b];
              e[f[1]](function() {
                var a = g && g.apply(this, arguments);
                a && $.isFunction(a.promise) 
                ? a.promise()
                  .done(c.resolve)
                  .fail(c.reject)
                  .progress(c.notify) 
                : c[f[0] + "With"](this === d 
                  ? c.promise() 
                  : this, g ? [a] : arguments)
              })
            }), a = null
          }).promise()
        },
        promise: function(a) {
          return null != a ? $.extend(a, d) : d
        }
      },
      e = {};
    return d.pipe = d.then, $.each(b, function(a, f) {
      var g = f[2],
        h = f[3];
      d[f[1]] = g.add, h && g.add(function() {
        c = h
      }, b[1 ^ a][2].disable, b[2][2].lock), e[f[0]] = function() {
        return e[f[0] + "With"](this === e ? d : this, arguments), this
      }, e[f[0] + "With"] = g.fireWith
    }), d.promise(e), a && a.call(e, e), e
  }

}(jQuery));

var p = {
  run: function() {
    return $()
      .promise()
      .then(function() {
        console.log("call together");
        console.log("call together");
        // do stuff
        // pass `data` to next `.then`
        return "call first";
      })
      .delay(2000)
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .delay(2000)
      .then(function() {
        console.log("call second");
      })
  }
};

p.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: OP gave very specific requirements of what he wants to write. Your answer doesn't comply to that. Imo it's even worse than his working solution with `.then(delay(2000))`

Comment: I'd think so, yes, although I wouldn't consider completely replacing `$.Deferred` with a different implementation to be a good solution. And if you intend to use `resolveWith`, then you should probably pass the original `this` and `arguments` from the `then` callback, not only the first parameter.

Comment: @Bergi Solution does not attempt to replace `$.Deferred` with a different implementation; aside from `delay`, `js` at post is source of `$.Deferred` from version jQuery  "1.11.2" . Yes, agree with passing original `this` and `arguments` . Was initially testing whether `$.Deferred()` would indeed return `delay` if called within `delay`; initial attempts allowed `.delay` to be defined at first call, then `undefined` when called second time chained to first method. btw, _" Imo it's even worse than his working solution with `.then(delay(2000))`"_ did inspire to "comply" Thanks! See updated post

Comment: Yeah, it's overwriting `$.Deferred` with the *same* implementation - and I would consider that copy-paste-programming a problem, not necessarily from the functionality but the maintainability perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I wrap `$.Deferred(afterBuild)` and wrap original `afterBuild` that in turn wraps `.promise(obj)` method, extending given `obj` with custom `delay` method. Which uses `window.setTimeout`:

Note: it only delays `done` branch.

```js
function extendPromises(extensions) {
    $.Deferred = (function (originalDeferred) {
        return function (afterBuild) {
            var newAfterBuild = function (d) {
                d.promise = (function (originalPromise) {
                    return function (obj) {
                        return originalPromise.call(this, $.extend(obj, extensions));
                    };
                })(d.promise);
                if (afterBuild) afterBuild.apply(this, arguments);
                return this;
            };
            return originalDeferred.call(this, newAfterBuild);
        };
    })($.Deferred);
}

extendPromises({
    delay: function (delay) {
        return this.then(function (value) {
            var d = $.Deferred();
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                d.resolve(value);
            }, delay);
            return d.promise();
        });
    }
});

// so now I can do:
$.when("hello")
.then(function (value) { $("#log").append(value+"\n"); return value; })
.delay(1000)
.then(function (value) { $("#log").append(value); return value; });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="log" rows=5></textarea>
```